# Grafana link variables together

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a dashboard with two variable that I want to link together e.g

CoreEnv{a,b,c}, awsEnv{aa,bb,cc} whenever coreEnv is selected on a I want awsEnv to be set to aa.
Same with b and c. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what I wanted I had to do a bit of magic around regex to reference it within my prometheus datasouce so and then have that hidden and use the other as the selector. /.*${DataSource_Select:text:raw}*./ <- KVP pair stored as `a : aa, b : bb` so when I select a in the dropdown the datasource value uses the regex to pick a as the value and the awsEnv I can also reference doing ${DataSource_Select:raw} to get aa